# Firewall/Block Compute Engine to only allow connections from App Engine (Flexible?)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have CouchDB server on a Google Compute Engine via Bitnami.

I want my API (Google App Engine) to be able to talk to Compute Engine but I really don't want anyone else to be able to for security purposes.

I'm open to using App Engine Flexible if that's what needs to happen.

It says [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) that google app engine can't be assigned a static IP but I was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions of restricting outside access to the static ip I've assigned my compute engine to only allow incoming connections made to my Projects/My app engine, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring to use Virtual Private Cloud (VPC), since this option allows you to configure firewall rules in order to provide a controlled access to your Cloud resources and allow then to interact in a safe environment.

You can give a look to the VPC overview to have a better understanding of the capabilities and options offered by Google Cloud (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) and also you will find useful information on how to use the VPC over the different services in the docs (https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options). By the way, you would need to move your API to  App Engine Flex.